# Правильность кода(mvc)

Tags: php, mvc

Контроллер:

```
class Controller_Login extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new Model_Portfolio();
        $this->view = new View();
        //Проверка авторизован ли пользователь
        Session::init();
        $logged = Session::get('authorized');
        if($logged == true) {           
            header('Location: ../');            
        }
    }

    function action_index()
    {           
        $data = $this->model->login();
        $this->view->generate('login_view.php', 'template_view.php', $data);
    }

    function action_logout()
    {           
        $this->model->logout();
    }   
}
```

Правильно ли проверять пользователя на авторизованность в контроллере или лучше перенести в модель?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В концепции MVC - ни в контроллере, ни в модели. Модель вообще не знает о том, что такое авторизация, контроллер занимается тем, что, грубо говоря, перенаправляет потоки данных - берет сущности из модели и зашвыривает их в представление, при этом не имея ни малейшего понятия о том авторизован ли юзер. Формально он может пользоваться только каким-то источником данных о правах пользователя, чтобы правильно перенаправить данные и выбрать представление, но пользователь вообще не должен попасть в контроллер, если он не имеет прав на эту операцию. Поэтому авторизацией должен заниматсья фреймворк, стоящий перед контроллером, а вы так или иначе должно сказать этому фреймворку, необходимо ли авторизация для доступа в те или иные места.

В случае, если выбор ограничивается только двумя стульями - лучше в контроллере. Лучше раздувать контроллер, потому что его банально легче чистить, и он более терпелив к таким вещам; если же вы запихнете авторизацию в модель, то вы уже не сможете, например, нормально организовать рассылку писем, потому что для этого (!) потребуется вторизация.

Comment: А если я не использую фреймворк?

Comment: @edvardpotter я бы сильно не советовал идти этим путем. В любом случае вы так или иначе пишете свой, потому что (например) контроллеры же вызываются каким-то роутером.

Comment: роутер есть, только не могу понять как в нем прописать проверку на авторизованность.

Comment: @edvardpotter это не в роутере должно быть. Концепция MVC описывает только основу приложения, пряча очень много всего, что лежит вне нее - любая бизнес-логика на самом деле реализуется в сервисах, которые лежат на непонятном уровне между моделью (хранением данных) и контроллером (а иногда, наоборот, сверху контроллера). У вас так или иначе должен появиться сервис авторизации в виде middleware - он должно анализировать входящий запрос (на наличие нужных заголовков/кук) - и разрешать или запрещать дальнейшую обработку (де-факто перенаправляя на контроллер "доступ запрещен").

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю что правильнее в контролере, т.к. модель работает с данными.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем согласен. Авторизация и работа с пользователями должна быть предусмотрена внутрянкой, самой системой ( т.е. ее компонентами ). Контроллерам и моделям должно быть фиолетово на то обрабатывается пользователь или нет, до того момента когда вы явно не укажите что в этот метод контроллера может иметь доступ только пользователь с правом "someRule" ( RBAC ). В то же время, пользователь - это сущность в БД, сессии... Должна быть модель которая отвечает за работу с этой сущностью - получение, создание, редактирование, обновление, удаление...